# Is there a energetically low way to chemically degrade / destroy cement and concrete?

Tags: cement

Personally I dislike cement and concrete. Nothing grows on it, it's hard and unconfortable and exists for cars rather than living beings. There are some concrete spots in front of my house where I would gleefully put plants or even plant a tree if possible.

Of course, breaking the concrete plate already requires plenty of physical effort hitting it with a sledge hammer or a noisy hydraulic one, and even then there's all the rubble that is supposed to go to a landfill.

I know cement / concrete is a special mix of calcium and some other carbonates and hydroxides. I suppose its surface pH must be too alkaline for microbial attack but acids should be able to dissolve it. Is there a specific way to degrade it using a combination of microorganisms and maybe some organic substrate?